# SwiftUI: WHere can I get a list of standard colors?

Tags: macos, colors, swiftui, themes

In SwiftUI I can assign a color using something like this:

```
Text("…")
.background(Color.something)
```

I know that I can select a number of hard-coded colours, as well as my own custom colours.

I want to use the standard colours for MacOS appearance theme (I’m not sure what the correct terminology is for that). In particular, I would like to get the standard text background colour (which in the light appearance is white).

Does SwiftUI have access to these colours, and, if so, where can I find them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you meant this

```
Text("…")
.background(Color(NSColor.textBackgroundColor))
```

And full list is in [UI Element Colors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/ui_element_colors)

Comment: That’s exactly what I was looking for. `UI Element Colors`. Is there anything you don’t know about SwiftUI?